# How to aggregate the data into these form using SQL or Redshift?

Tags: sql

For example: A ATM Machine fault data
s_id: Bank Branch
atm_id: Multiple atm on each branch
start_time: Ticket is created for fault occur
end_time: Ticket is closed 
aggregate the overlapping data with group by s_id,atm_id

**Raw Data**

[image: Raw Data]

**Output Required**

[image: Output Required]

Comment: Just tag the database software you're using, not a bunch of different ones.

Comment: Also, provide table definition(s), sample data (Preferrably as create table and insert statements), and expected results from that sample in your question itself, not as links to images.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a self-join with some aggregation

```
SELECT t1.s_id, t1.atm_id, 
 MIN(t2.start_time) as start_time,
 MAX(t2.end_time) as end_time
FROM YourTable t1
LEFT JOIN YourTable t2 
  ON t2.s_id = t1.s_id 
 AND t2.atm_id = t1.atm_id
 AND t2.start_time <= t1.end_time
 AND t2.end_time >= t1.start_time
GROUP BY t1.s_id, t1.atm_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a gaps-and-islands problem, because you want to identify "islands" of `s_id`, `atm_id`, and `status` that are on adjacent rows.

That suggests the difference of row numbers for this incarnation:

```
select s_id, atm_id, status_code,
       min(start_time), max(end_time)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by s_id, atm_id order by start_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by s_id, atm_id, status_code order by start_time) as seqnum_s
      from t
     ) t
group by s_id, atm_id, status_code, (seqnum - seqnum_s);
```

Why this finds adjacent rows with the same status is a little tricky to explain.  However, if you look at the results of the subquery, I think you will see how the difference identifies the adjacent rows that you want to combine together.